# ERROR when running bundle install on 'stripe' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am having a problem installing the stripe gem for processing payments. Not sure what the exact problem is and how to fix it.

Here is the error I am receiving:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151013-3015-1x97asm.rb extconf.rb
>   checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>       --with-opt-dir
>       --without-opt-dir
>       --with-opt-include
>       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>       --with-opt-lib
>       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>       --with-make-prog
>       --without-make-prog
>       --srcdir=.
>       --curdir
>   2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>       --with-static-libstdc++
>       --without-static-libstdc++
>       --with-stdc++lib
>       --without-stdc++lib.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>
> You have to install development tools first.
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> An error occurred while installing `unf_ext (0.0.7.1),` and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: please add environment details such as OS

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that I had an Xcode update to do. Now that it's updated it works fine.